# PHP 5.6.2 - SOAP WSDL Authentication issue

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework, wsdl

I am new to SOAP and I've been searching for a few hours now, I've tried many of the solutions proposed on other questions at stackoverflow, but unfortunately I am unable to solve my issue.

**The issue:** I am unable to authenticate myself through a SOAP request to reach a protected WSDL file. I am using the programming language: PHP with PHP version: 5.6.20.

**Response message:** `string(347) "a:InvalidSecurityAn error occurred when verifying security for the message."`

**Note:** I have verified my credentials multiple times, and I've let the third-party to which I am connecting verify my credentials as well. I tried making a request through the program: SoapUI version: 5.2.1 and this succeeded.

**Test request code:**

```
const SOAP_URL = 'https://www.someurl.com/DataService.svc?wsdl';

$options = array(
            'login' => '*****',
            'password' => '*****',
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => 1,
            'cache_wsdl'=> WSDL_CACHE_NONE
        );

$request = new SoapClient(self::SOAP_URL, $options);
$request->getMessageTypes();

var_dump($request->__getLastResponse());
```

Thanks!